# Open QGIS without recent projects

Tags: qgis

Is there a way (command line flag?) to open QGIS without displaying the recent projects list? Usually when giving demonstrations or similar I'll simply use a separate user profile on my computer to avoid leaking sensitive data, but sometimes I have to display a project I'm working on to other people, and then I'd like QGIS to be in as much of an “incognito mode” as possible.

(I do realize that I could set the number of recent projects to 0 under the advanced settings, but I'm looking for a more temporary solution here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grab the divider between current projects & templates, drag it fully to the left, aaaaand they're gone. Temporarily.

[image]

Comment: I was writing the same solution. :)

Comment: Ahhh, this is stupidly simple but perfect! Thanks!